# Ruby on Rails: Model Association with multiple foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-associations, rails-activerecord

I am working on a `User` model, and each user should be able to have both students and teachers. However, since *student* and *teacher* are both a type of `User`, my model got a little complicated.

This is what I am trying right now.

**Teacher_student_link**

```
class TeacherStudentLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :student_id, :teacher_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :teacher, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :student, :class_name => "User"
end
```

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teacher_student_links, :foreign_key => { :student_id, :teacher_id }, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :students, :through => :teacher_student_links
  has_many :teachers, :through => :teacher_student_links
end
```

If everything works as I intended, I should be able to do

```
@user = User.new
@user.students
@user.teachers
@user.student.teachers
```

I think the only problem with above is that I can't give two foreign keys at the same time to `teacher_student_link`, but I'm not sure. As a workaround, I don't have teacher_id in my model yet, and just doing `student.user` to call the `teacher`. Can anyone help me with this issue?

**Update:**
With the solution below, how should I create a new link?

```
def become_student
  @user = user.find(params[:id])
  @student_link = @user.student_links.create(:student_id => current_user.id)
  @teacher_link = current_user.teacher_links.create(:teacher_id => @user.id)
end
```

If I do it like this, is the student and teacher paired up correctly?
I am confused a little because in the TeacherStudentLink, there are `user`, `student`, `teacher`, and I'm not sure how to deal with creating links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should separate out the teacher_student_links association into two associations:

```
  has_many :teacher_links, :foreign_key => :student_id, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "TeacherStudentLink"
  has_many :student_links, :foreign_key => :teacher_id, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "TeacherStudentLink"
  has_many :students, :through => :student_links
  has_many :teachers, :through => :teacher_links
```

You might need to add the foreign keys to the belongs_to association on TeacherStudentLink also

**Update:**

Regarding your second question about creating links, the following should work:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.students << current_user
```

The TeacherStudentLink should be created automatically, and your associations should work if everything is set up correctly.

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Wait, I have one more question though. I'm confused what I have to do when I want to create a link. Could you check my update?