# How to do associations with two user types and one model with has and belongs to many relationships in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now. Looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391962/ruby-on-rails-model-association-with-multiple-foreign-keys), but it is not exactly what I need.

I have three models: User, Group, GroupMembership. User can be a teacher and a student, so user has different Roles through UserRoles table. Groups can have multiple teachers. What I want is something like this:

```
Role.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :users  #this works fine

User.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles  # this works fine

has_many :group_memberships
has_many :groups, through: :group_memberships
has_many :teachers, through: :group_memberships
has_many :students, through: :group_memberships

Group.rb
has_many :students, through: :group_memberships
has_many :teachers, through: :group_memberships

GroupMembership.rb
belongs_to :student
belongs_to :teacher
belongs_to :group
```

User with roles works fine, there is no problem with the different roles for user. The problem is with group memberships. The above is just something that I want to work, but in some cases I need to supply source or class name and I am not sure what exactly to do. And what kind of migrations should I create?

Comment: How do you know a user is a teacher or a student? Is there a field that set the user type?

Comment: @AnezioCampos Yes, there is a table Roles and a join table UserRoles

Comment: @Dan add  `type` field to `User`, and make two inherits from `User` to student and teacher.

Comment: do you plan to use role to detect difference between students and teachers?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ he is using Roles to distinguish between the different types of User. IMHO thats a much better alternative than STI as STI makes it impossible to join.

Comment: You need [`source:`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4632472/1143732) option but I don't have massive experience with it

Comment: @Max you can join with STI, nay?

Comment: @RichPeck since STI relies on information in the DB on what kinds of classes to load and what kinds of relations they have its pretty hard to create effective joins VS the normal case. Not impossible - but makes everything very *interesting*. Its pretty much the same as when using polymorphic relations.

Answer (score 0):

I'll delete this if required; I'm pretty sure you'd benefit from using `source`: in your `User` and `Group` models:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :roles  # this works fine

   has_many :group_memberships
   has_many :groups,   through: :group_memberships

   has_many :teachers, through: :group_memberships, source: :teacher
   has_many :students, through: :group_memberships, source: :student
end

#app/models/group_membership.rb
class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :teacher, class_name: "User"

  belongs_to :group
end

#app/models/group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   has_many :students, through: :group_memberships, source: :student
   has_many :teachers, through: :group_memberships, source: :teacher
end
```

This is not tested & I don't have super experience with `source` so it could be wrong.

Comment: You're on the right track - however using two different columns on the `GroupMembership` join table is not a very good solution.

Comment: Certainly; I'll leave it until the OP looks. Appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

The modeling is a bit off - `GroupMembership` should be acting as a many to many join model. That means that each user and group needs a GroupMembership to tie them together.

Also you would alter the relation between users and roles to be a `has_many through:` so that you can have metadata in the join model.

```
class User
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :group_memberships
end

class Role
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end

class UserRole
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class Group
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :users, through: :group_memberships
end

class GroupMembership
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

To query for group users with a specific role you could now use:

```
teachers = group.users.where(users: { roles: [Role.find_by(name: 'teacher')])
```

To make this a bit more convenient we can setup special relations with conditions:

```
class Group
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :users, through: :group_memberships
  has_many :teachers, ->{ where(users: { roles: [Role.find_by(name: 'teacher')] }) } through: :group_memberships, source: :user
end
```

Note that we need to specify `source` as it tells AR that "teacher" is in fact `group_memberships.user`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. With your solution there would be a problem if a student of a certain group will also have a role as a teacher. So I need to distinguish where users in a group are students and when they are teachers.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Rolify and how they solved it

Comment: Rolify uses a polymorpic relationship between roles and the resource that the role applies to. So in your case you would either add a group_id to users_roles or make the relation polymorphic so that roles can be applied to different resources.